# Editing file in Rails (using text area)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, text, web

I want to edit file stored on HDD with Rails in this way:
1. Open file and load content to 'text_area' (or any other field where i can edit it)
2. Edit content in that 'text_area'
3. Save changes to that file

I have some code here:

1) [controller]

> ```
>  def show
>     @myfile = File.read("/home/pi/www/web-svn/repositories/Repo2/hooks/post-commit.tmpl")
>  end
> ```

2) [view]

> ```
> <%= text_area_tag(:message, @myfile, :size => "100x60") %>
> ```

3) ???

Here is the problem, how to pass edited text to controller again and save changes.
If you have better idea for whole procedure you can pass all usefull code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller's edit() method, determine the filename from the URL and read the file contents from the specified file into an instance variable (@myfile). Render the view, which is passed to the browser, edited by the user, and the edited text passed back to the server as POST data. Rails puts the POST data into the params hash and calls the controller's update() method. In update() the filename is determined from the URL, its modified contents retrieved from the params hash and written to the file. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Added:

This is off the top of my head and untested, so treat it as pseudo-code, but it should get you going in the right direction. I'm sure the design can be improved.

Your `form_tag` should look like below. It specifies the controller, the action, and the method for the request back to the server. The `:file` appears because a RESTful route should specify the resource to be updated (see below).

```
form_tag({:controller => :hooks, :action => :update, :file => @myfilename}, {:method => :put}) do
[...]
end
```

So, how do you pass the filename to the browser so it can come back with the update request? In one RESTful design, your URLs could look like `/hooks/:action/:file`. The value of `:file` would specify the file resource, and if you set up your routes to use this form, `params[:file]` will be available in your controller. Have your controller do

```
def edit
    @myfilename = params[:file]
    @myfile     = File.read(@myfilename)
end
```

and then the form_tag above should work. I'll leave the encoding of the filename and setting up the routes to you.